# Exporting apply results to CSV

Tags: r

I am looking to export the results of sapply function that sums the count of missing values in columns in a data frame to a new data frame, and then export that to a .csv file. The data and code are below.

Is there a way to easily save and export the results?

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c(1, 3, 3, 4, 5),
             var2=c(7, 7, NA, 3, 2),
             var3=c(3, 3, NA, 6, 8),
             var4=c(1, 1, 2, 8, NA))

#---Keep columns of interest 
keep <- c("var1", 
          "var2", 
          "var3", 
          "var4")
df_keep <- df[keep]

#---Generate count of missing
sapply(df_keep, function(x) sum (is.na(x)))

var1 var2 var3 var4 

0     1     1     1
```

Comment: What’s wrong with `colSums`? You also want to know whether the output should have any labeling as well what class is returned. ( I would have guess it was a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

```
write.csv(t(colSums(is.na(df[keep]))), "test.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

breaking it down

```
temp <- is.na(df[keep])

temp
# matrix with NA values being TRUE

      var1  var2  var3  var4
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

temp <- colSums(temp)

temp
# named list with counts

var1 var2 var3 var4 
   0    1    1    1 

temp <- t(temp)
# transpose the named list, you get a matrix you can write to csv

temp

     var1 var2 var3 var4
[1,]    0    1    1    1

# now write to csv without rownames
write.csv(temp, "test.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```